# Como formatar nome de campos no output das mensagens de validação do Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estou utilizando `$this->validate()` para realizar a validação de campos no Laravel, como posso aplicar um sublinhado no nome dos campos de forma automática no output de todas as mensagens referente a erro de validação?

Estou utilizando Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a classe `OutputFormatterStyle` e os metodos `getFormatter` e `setStyle`

Exemplo:

```
   use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyle;

   // ...

   function OutputHandler($sua_ saida)
   {
        $style = new OutputFormatterStyle('white', array('underscore'));
        $this->command->output->getFormatter()->setStyle('underscored', $style);

       $this->command->output->writeln('<underscored>'.$sua_ saida.'</underscored>');
    }
```

Coloque dentro de um model, e sempre use o handler para dar o output que precisar colocar o o sublinhado:

```
$class = new ClasseQueRepresentar();
$class->OutputHandler('algo');
```

Fonte: https://stillat.com/blog/2016/12/03/custom-command-styles-with-laravel-artisan